# ASP.NET development server cannot find localhost ?

Tags: asp.net

I have a web site opened in VS 2008 . I try to run it from VS2008 and the asp.net development server starts up.But the browser returns the following error
Firefox can't find the server at www.localhost.

The web address in browser is http://localhost:2921/WebSite2/Default2.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as www.localhost, and nothing built-in to asp.net will redirect you automatically (unless you tell it to).  Sounds like you have code that looks at the url and redirects to a www version if you're not there. You shouldn't do that, and instead use relative urls internally that work no matter which way a user hits a page.

Answer (score 0):

Check following :

1. Are your proxy settings correct in your Firefox browser. Firefox->Tools->Options->Network->Settings.
2. Are you browsing the correct address, everytime you run/debug your website a dynamic port is assigned unless explicitly specified.